# Error with the Feedburner for my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, feedburner

This is my Wordpress website: https://noshdaily.com/

The https://noshdaily.com/feed/ feed is already there, however, when I am trying to use https://feedburner.google.com I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred connecting to the URL: internal error
```

After that when I do confirm validity now it takes me here: http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3a%2f%2fnoshdaily.com%2f

and generates the following error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Still evidently an issue.  Your SSL/TLS certificate is not valid - no trusted root certificate.

https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https://noshdaily.com/feed/